# What does capital A mean in vector field notation?

Tags: notation, physics, vector-fields

This might be a dumb question but I am stuck halfway through an assignment where I am supposed to draw a bunch of vector fields because I don't understand an element of the notation.

The equation that is causing me trouble is the one below, describing a vector field in the plane, not including (0,0).

$\textbf{v}= \frac{-Ay}{r^2}\textbf{i}+\frac{Ax}{r^2}\textbf{j}; r^2=x^2+y^2$

The assignment does not include any addition on the capital A, so I assume that it has some conventional use that I am not familiar with?

Comment: It looks like an arbitrary constant.

Comment: it appears to just be a scalar constant.

Comment: People may have trouble understanding the question (or may simply not try) due to the notation. To fix this, start here: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: Could it be $A_y$ and $A_x$, the components of a vector $A$?

Comment: @BernardMassé Could be, but the only vector given in the problem is **v**, so it would be a bit odd

Comment: @DavidK and lulu Okay, so I should just ignore it when I sketch the vector field?

Comment: @DavidK Thanks, didn't know I could use LaTeX notation, it should be easier to read now. :-)

Comment: This is the type of question you should be asking whoever gave you that assignment. A bunch of strangers guessing could hardly offer you a sensible answer

Comment: @YuriyS You are probably right, I was just wondering if it was an example of conventional use that I wasn't aware of. But I will try to contact my TA :-)

Comment: Capital A often denotes vector potential of magnetic field, and sometimes vector potential of other fields, so that's one possible interpretation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If nothing else is said about it, I would assume $A$ is meant to be an arbitrary real number. For the drawing, I would assume $A > 0,$ since for $A=0$ you get a zero vector field and for $A < 0$ all the vectors will reverse direction.